# Facing issue when invoking a method from WCF webservice (under HTTPS) from WCFTestclient

Tags: c#, wcf

I am invoking a method from WCFTestClient tool and it is giving me following error:

**There was no endpoint listening at https://example.com/MarketYardWebService/SchedulerClasses/MailIntimations.svc/MailIntimations.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.**

My Web.config is as follows:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>   
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MarketYardWebService.SchedulerClasses.MailIntimations">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>  
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="IncreasedTimeout" openTimeout="00:25:00" sendTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:00" receiveTimeout="00:25:00">
            </binding>


            <!--*****************************************************-->

            <binding name="TransportSecurity">
            <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            </security>
            </binding>
            <!--****************************************************-->

        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <!--*****************************************************-->
    <services>
        <service  behaviorConfiguration="MarketYardWebService.SchedulerClasses.MailIntimations" name="MarketYardWebService.SchedulerClasses.MailIntimations">
            <endpoint address="MailIntimations.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="MarketYardWebService.SchedulerClasses.IMailIntimations">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />   
        </service>
    </services>
    <!--*****************************************************-->


    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />

</system.serviceModel>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

The URL address is proper which is connecting to my UAT server from my local environment.

Please can anybody help me as to what is missing in my web.config to sort out this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your service's behavior name and service name are same and hence the problem.Try renaming the service behavior to metadata.

```
 <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="metadatadiscovery">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Now bind this metadata to your exposed service.

```
 <services>
        <service  behaviorConfiguration="metadatadiscovery" name="MarketYardWebService.SchedulerClasses.MailIntimations">
            <endpoint address="MailIntimations" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" contract="MarketYardWebService.SchedulerClasses.IMailIntimations">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />   
        </service>
    </services>
```